# Issues with background-attachment: fixed in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I was having an issue with images flickering in chrome. Didn't happen in firefox, and it didn't always happen, but when it did it was really annoying. It was happening when I hovered over another image that had an effect that occurred when I hovered over it, and right as I hovered over that image, another image that was set as a background image for another area would "flicker" or "blink" briefly and then reload. When I moved my mouse off of the image, the other area would flicker/blink again.

EDIT: Okay, still having issues. I have narrowed it down to this

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

This is the issue. At [my website](http://jacquelynchastain.com/test) if you position your screen between the 'Web Design' button and the picture of me, then click on 'Web Design', the background in the 'About' section briefly disappears. The only way to make this stop is to remove the fixed position from the background image. Please help! I've been researching this for days now and I thought I had it fixed...

**ANSWER** (August 07, 2014): Seeing as this question has gotten quite a number of views, I should let ya'll know I found a solution. [See it live here](http://jacquelynchastain.com/) It would seem that I had some junky JS that was conflicting with a lot of different things on my page. Primarily this happened with my "Work" section button, as I had a hover function set up via JS/CSS. Now that it's pure CSS, the issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be the solution for every issue, but it was for me.

I had:

```
  background: url("../img/picture.jpg") no-repeat fixed 0% 100%;
```

Which I changed to

```
  background: url("../img/picture.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
```

And from that point on the flickering stopped. Just wanted to share, as I see it is kind of common problem with Chrome. I would assume that you could also do the same with no-repeat and fixed, but it wasn't necessary for me. If you're having image-flickering issues with Chrome, I would suggest separating out the different properties regarding the image and see if it works. It's a little more code, but it might help!

Comment: Interesting! No sooner do I solve my own problem and think its helpful, I'm having the same issue due to some jQuery firing. Time to do more research...